# Python, tkinter: How do I snap the mouse pointer to the center of a window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I need to create a window in Python, the best way by far is tkinter so I went with that. Mouse looking is going to be used: I need to make it so my mouse cursor is always snapped to the center of this window after calculating movement. I looked at every solution but can't get this seemingly simple thing to work. I prefer a way that doesn't require importing other libraries, doing it from tkinter itself seems most ideal... also I'm not creating any other windows or widgets, I only have my main window running. Of course I want it to work cross-platform, in my case Linux (KDE, Wayland). So far I tried 3 options, I'll share the relevant parts of my class which is started with `window = Window()`

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.event_generate("<Motion>", warp = True, x = 50, y = 50)
        self.root.mainloop()
```

Result: Does nothing, mouse cursor is still free. In this case it's likely because the `event_generate` doesn't have a cause so it won't run each frame... as such I went ahead and connected it to a trigger, but that won't work either:

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.bind("<KeyPress>", self.onKeyPress)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def onKeyPress(self, event):
        self.root.event_generate("<Motion>", warp = True, x = 50, y = 50)
```

Result: This should have snapped the mouse pointer when any key is pressed, a print confirms the `onKeyPress` event runs but cursor position is not affected.

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.bind("<Motion>", self.onMouseMove)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def onMouseMove(self, event):
        self.root.event_generate("<Motion>", warp = True, x = 50, y = 50)
```

Result: Crashes with an infinite loop error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Edit: Since my window will contain a `canvas` element spanning the full size, I attempted to use `icursor` on its widget as suggested by other answers. While I can draw on the canvass successfully, not even this will affect the mouse cursor when it hovers over the element... neither does running `self.canvas.focus()` or `self.canvas.focus_set()` anywhere.

```
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width = 400, height = 200)
self.canvas.icursor(50, 50)
self.canvas.pack()
```

Comment: Your first block of code works for me on OSX - the cursor warps to the given coordinates. Are you expecting it to be frozen there?

Comment: Strange, could it be platform related? I'm on Manjaro Linux / KDE Plasma / Wayland if this may be relevant. I want each frame to teleport the cursor back to the center of the window, after seeing how much it has moved from the center to extract the movement vector.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "each frame" - frame of animation? Instance of `tk.Frame`? Something else.

Comment: I'll definitely be creating my own thread / multiprocessing function to do certain things at a fixed interval, say 100 times per second. It's at this interval that I: Want to check how far the cursor has moved from the window origin (already got that), then move the cursor back at the center so the process can be repeated next frame.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not good at English, so I rely on a translator.

I am a Windows user.

I don't know if you're talking about this kind of behavior.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window:

    MOTION_FLAG = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.bind("<KeyPress>", self.onKeyPress)
        self.root.bind("<Motion>", self.onMouseMove)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def onKeyPress(self, event):
        self.root.event_generate("<Motion>", warp=True, x=50, y=50)

    def onMouseMove(self, event):
        if Window.MOTION_FLAG:
            Window.MOTION_FLAG = 0
        else:
            Window.MOTION_FLAG = 1
            self.root.event_generate("<Motion>", warp=True, x=50, y=50)

Window()
```

Comment: I tried your example just as described, pasted the whole thing in my `init.py` to make sure there's no mistakes. No result: I don't get any errors either, but no matter where I move the mouse or what keys I press in the process absolutely nothing happens. Wonder if a bug that only affects tkinter on Linux / KDE Plasma / Wayland may also be involved here.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to use another library, but still  you might wanna give pyautogui a try. It works on mac, linux and windows and can handle your cursor. Not sure about the refresh time though.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui


def motion(event):
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    print(x, y)
    pyautogui.moveTo(
        root.winfo_x() + root.winfo_width() / 2,
        root.winfo_y() + root.winfo_height() / 2
    )


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
root.bind('<Motion>', motion)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If nothing else works I might try that. Apparently Manjaro Linux doesn't offer `pyautogui` so I'd need to get it separately. Does it work as an alternative to `tkinter` so I'm not relying on two things that do the same stuff, or are they meant to be used alongside each other?

Comment: If you just want to move your cursor, you'll only need pyautogui. `pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)` will move your cursor where ever you want to have it